# SSIS deployed package execution using parameter at runtime

Tags: sql, ssis, sql-server-agent

I have a package which is deployed using SQL server agent.
I am executing the SQL server agent by calling a stored procedure.
i have declared some variables inside the ssis package ,i want to use these variables as parameter in stored procedure.
any body Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use a sql script task and pass a parameter to it.

Comment: But how can i get the values of variable in sql server scheduler job executing time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use xp_cmdshell you could use dtexec to execute the package from a stored procedure . Passing a parameter can be done like this:

exec xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /f "c:demo\demo.dtsx" set \package.configurations[Configuration1].properties[Variable].value;int-002'

This is not a best practice. I would prefer to use my stored procedure to write my variables to a table first and then read from that table in SSIS with an Execute SQL statement as you can read here [Populate an SSIS variable using a SQL statement](https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/08/how-to-set-and-use-variables-in-ssis-execute-sql-task/)